# Issue creating Data extension row using MC SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am referring to [MC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_data_to_data_extension_object.htm) to create a DE row using SOAL API

However, I am having issues with this piece of code:

client.Create(new PartnerAPIS7.CreateOptions(), objects, out requestId, out overallStatus);

While running the project in Visual Studio, I am getting following error message when I invoke the SOAP API call:
"An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Security requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not present in the incoming message."

Please note that I am providing the security credentials as: 
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxx"; 
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxx";

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Or any insights into what I might be missing?

Thanks.